# Runtime.getRuntime().exec(): executing touch creates a directory when executing after mkdir

Tags: java

When I execute this line of code:

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"mkdir", "-p", "/home/stuff/Keyring", "&& touch", "/home/stuff/Keyring/keyring.gpg"});
```

the messaging.gpg inside the Keyring folder is created as a directory instead of a file and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're executing `mkdir` with the following arguments:

```
"-p", "/home/stuff/Keyring", "&& touch", "/home/stuff/Keyring/keyring.gpg"
```

(the first argument to `exec()` is the process to execute) so the -p tells `mkdir` to build parent directories if required, and the remaining arguments *are the directories to create*. Hence your problem/issue (I suspect you'll have a dir somewhere called '`&& touch`')

It looks like you want to execute a shell script, so you need to encapsulate the above as such e.g. provide arguments such as:

```
/bin/sh -c "mkdir -p /home/stuff/Keyring && touch /home/stuff/Keyring/keyring.gpg"
```

i.e. you're executing `/bin/sh`, and providing the commands on the shell command line.

Or better still, use the `java.io.File` API or similar, and avoid forking processes altogether?

Comment: Executing the command in the Terminal works completely fine though.

Comment: @Samuel That is exactly the point. The terminal is a shell. What is executed by `exec()` isn't, unless you make it so.

Comment: Runtime.exec() executes a process. It doesn't execute a process *within* a shell. A common confusion!